# Распределение ресурсов между пользователями БД

Tags: sql-server

Мне нужно распределить доступ пользователей к ресурсам БД. Я так полагаю, что делать это надо с помощью схем. В официальной документации при создании схемы создается и таблица. Мне же нужно предоставить доступ уже к созданным таблицам. Каким образом это можно сделать?
И вообще можно предоставить доступ к таблице с ограничениями? То есть, создать схему с условием (WHERE), по которому будет предоставляться доступ к ресурсам уже созданной таблицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего создать роли базы данных, предоставить нужный доступ роли и задавать каждому пользователю необходимые роли

Для этого есть серия системных процедур и команд:
CREATE ROLE (sp_addrole) - добавить роль
sp_addrolemember - добавить роль имени входа

ну и обычные инструкции DCL - GRANT, REVOKE, DENY